# Android hide content of CoordinatorLayout when scrolling

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-tablayout

I have `CoordinatorLayout` with `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `TabLayout`, `ViewPager` and `TextView` in main content. The problem is when I scroll down, `TextView` and `TabLayout` don't hide.

How can I hide It when I'm scrolling down? Please, help

Screenshots:

[image]

I can scroll content of `ViewPager`.

[image]